# Swagger schema not showing custom value of enum

Tags: java, enums, jackson, swagger

I have created an enum which also stores a value

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;

public enum AnimalType {
  DOG("dog"),
  CAT("cat"),

  private final String displayName;

  AnimalType(String displayName) {
    this.displayName = displayName;
  }

  @JsonValue
  public String getDisplayName() {
    return displayName;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return displayName;
  }
}
```

I am creating enum in this way because the user will give me input `dog` or `cat`. The enum value is getting serialized and deserialized properly.

But the `swagger.json` is showing `DOG` and `CAT` in place of `dog` and `cat`. I don't want the user to see the internal enum name and since the schema will be used by the users, I want to display the `dog` or `cat` in the schema.

```
        "type" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "enum" : [ "DOG", "CAT"]
        },
```

I have tried using `@JsonProperty` annotation( like `@JsonProperty("dog")`), but that didn't solve the problem. Can you please guide me on how I can solve this problem?

Versions:
swagger: 2.0
jackson: 2.7.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried various alternatives to make it work such as

```
public enum AnimalType {
  @JsonProperty("dog") DOG("dog"),
  @JsonProperty("cat") CAT("cat"),
```

or using `@JsonCreator` as suggested by @sercheo_87. But the schema was not showing the required value.

I found out that it is a bug in [swagger-core](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/2707). Taking a updated version of swagger helped me. Also they are backporting the changes to this version.

Answer (score 1):

Test your code with

```
@JsonCreator
public static AnimalType fromString(String key) {
    return displayName == null
            ? null
            : AnimalType.valueOf(key.toUpperCase());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @sercheo_87 for help. But the proposed solution didn't solve my problem, the schema still contains "DOG" instead of  "dog". Also, did you intentionally had an enum name ("DOG"  and not "dog") in JSON property?

Comment: Thanks a lot  @sercheo_87, All the solutions you suggested were supposed to work as per the documentation. But somehow they are not working, thanks a lot.

Comment: See next blog for an example [How To Serialize and Deserialize Enums with Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-enums)

Comment: Thanks @sercheo_87, it seems that there was a bug in swagger-core that's why it was not working.